# How to fix VectorDrawableCompat configuration error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I created a project in Android studio. **Even without modifying any single character in the project I cannot run it.** It gives following error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.kk.myapplication/com.kk.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an
>   incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for
>   VectorDrawableCompat.

These are the codes.

**MainActivity.java :**

```
package com.kk.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kk.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kk.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

**build.gradle(Top Level)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I fix this issue? I did not change anything in the project Any Help be Appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you will get this issue.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214182

Solution was to upgrade the `gradle plugin to v2.0+ (upgraded to 2.1.0)`

add this in your dependency.

```
   {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
```

and sync the project.

**Edit :**

change this

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

to this

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: @WEAPI glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but another option might be for your activity to inherit from Activity instead of AppCompatActivity. There's probably a variety of other considerations that might come into play, but that worked for me.

Comment: you my friend are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is an issue with incompatible gradle version reported here.. [Google issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214182)

Updatating gradle version may fix this -

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add into your `build.gradle` files

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myApp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    generatedDensities = []
}

// This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}
```